# Getting error while adding product to cart

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I tried to add product programmatically. and i use below code

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$paramater = array(
            'product' => $product->getId(),
            'related_product' => null,
            'qty' => 1,
            'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
        );
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($paramater);
$cart->addProduct($product, $request);
$cart->save();
```

This code is working fine after login. but before login i am getting following error.

> a:5:{i:0;s:640:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_magento_nua`.`sales_flat_quote_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELE), query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `product_id`, `store_id`, `is_virtual`, `sku`, `name`, `is_qty_decimal`, `weight`, `qty`, `custom_price`, `product_type`, `original_custom_price`, `base_cost`) VALUES ('2019-06-11 12:17:58', '2019-06-11 12:17:58', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:2586:"#0 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Can some one help me to fix the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **`Mage::getModel()`**

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$paramater = array(
                'product' => $product->getId(),
                'related_product' => null,
                'qty' => 1,
                'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
            );
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($paramater);
$cart->addProduct($product, $request);
$cart->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution for this. since there is no quote i am not able to add item. i just need to initiate quote before adding product to cart. i use below code to adding a product now.

```
 $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
 $cart->init();
 $quote = $cart->getQuote();
 $paramater = array(
    'product' => $product->getId(),
    'qty' => 1,
    'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
 ); 
 $request = new Varien_Object();
 $request->setData($paramater);
 $quote->addProduct($product, $request);
 $quote->save();
 $cart->save();
```

Above code works as expected.